# Good source for Jordan Fréchet algebras

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras, locally-convex-spaces, jordan-algebras

Is there any good source for Jordan Fréchet (or more generally, Jordan locally convex) algebras?

I'm looking for something on the level similar to the level of the book "Banach and Locally Convex Algebras" by A. Helemskii, but for the non-associative (Jordan, to be precise) case.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not very knowledgeable about Jordan algebras in an infinite-dimensional context. However, I guess that they should appear in the work of Wolfgang Bertram. 

While his book on the subject 
https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540414261
seems to deal only with the finite-dimensional case I know that he is working with infinite-dimensional settings and is also active in Jordan geometry. I think you might be able to uncover more at his webpage:
http://www.iecl.univ-lorraine.fr/~Wolfgang.Bertram/#pcs

Comment: Thank you for the links. I know the work of Wolfgang Bertram (mainly because of his work on /generalized/ projective geometry and its relation to Jordan structures), but I have not seen there discussion of the Fréchet (or locally convex) case (may be I need to look once again).

The infinite-dimensional case is well developed for Jordan Banach algebras (and triples), but what I'm asking for is still a bit more general.

Comment: Yes and since the Frechet world is quite different from the Banach world I would assume there is a huge technical gap.